# Code igniter and jquery $.post()

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using jquery $.post() and updating a value in database using cod igniter. Now, how do i send the result to success call back in jquery.

This is what, I have tired.

**Model**

```
 class Test extends CI_Model{
    function update(){
           .....
        return $result = $this->db->update();

     }

   }
```

**Jquery**

```
 $.post(...,... , function(data,status) {
        alert(data);  **Says undefined**
        alert(status); **Says success**

     });
```

Since I am using update to update a value in database,  I am passing array from controller to model.Now when I use about mentioned in controller, I get Missing argument 1 as for update() function which makes sense, How do I get result of my model to controller ?

Comment: and your contorller??

Comment: @bipen:Updated my post.

Comment: What URL you are posting to? can you show content after `/index.php/`? and where is your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `echo` the variable. It will be received in the jquery. Try this,

Controller :

```
function index(){
  if($a = $this->Test_model->Update()){
    $data['rows'] = $a;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

Comment: :Since I have been using update() for updating value from jquery ajax and I am passing a parameter. Now If I call it in index(), it says parameter 1 missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Edwin Alex said you can send back the result through echo.

But

If you have enabled gzip in codeigniter echo would not work. You have to use the output class of the codeigniter

```
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

Just to let you know.